# Basic javascript solving quadratic equations

Tags: javascript, solver, quadratic

Very new programmer, trying to make a quadratic equation solver in javascript.

```js
//QuadSolver, a b c as in classic ax^2 + bx + c format
function quadsolve(x, a, b, c) {
  var sol = (
    ((a * (x * x)) + (b * x)) + c
    )
}
//Test
console.log(quadsolve(1, 1, 1, 0))
```

In the console, it outputs "undefined". Would this be the correct way to go about solving the problem? If so, how would I get a value instead of undefined? Thanks!

Comment: You don't return anything from the function, so there is an implicit return of `undefined`. Also note that isn't the *solution* for a quadratic expression...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: What are you trying to solve for? You're given all the values.

Comment: To give an example of what Jared write: before `}` in the method, type "return sol".

Comment: The return worked, thanks! And I was trying to solve for y in this equation

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said you need to use the "return" keyword to return a value. Are you trying to find the zeros of the equation? If so here is the numeric solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="https://www.desmos.com/api/v1.4/calculator.js?apiKey=dcb31709b452b1cf9dc26972add0fda6"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Quadratic Function</h3>
    <p>This is an example of the solution of the quadratic function using <a href="https://github.com/Pterodactylus/ceres.js">Ceres.js</a></p>
    <pre><code id="quadratic_demo_code" class="language-js"></code></pre>
    <div id="calculator" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script>
    var elt = document.getElementById('calculator');
    var calculator = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt);
    calculator.setExpression({ id: 'exp1', latex: 'x+10*y-20 = 0' });
    calculator.setExpression({ id: 'exp2', latex: "\\sqrt{5}*x-y^2 = 0" });
    </script>
    <p><textarea id="quadratic_demo" rows="40" cols="110"></textarea></p>
    <script id="quadratic_demo_code_source">
        async function ceresSolveQuadratic() {
            const {Ceres} = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Pterodactylus/Ceres.js@latest/dist/ceres.min.js');
    
            var fn1 = function f1(x){
                return (x[0]+10*x[1]-20); //this equation is of the for f1(x) = 0 
            }
    
            var fn2 = function f2(x){
                return (Math.sqrt(5)*x[0]-Math.pow(x[1], 2)); //this equation is of the for f2(x) = 0 
            }
            
            let solver = new Ceres()
            solver.addFunction(fn1) //Add the first equation to the solver.
            solver.addFunction(fn2) //Add the second equation to the solver.
            //solver.addCallback(c1) //Add the callback to the solver.
            //solver.addLowerbound(0,1.6) //Add a lower bound to the x[0] variable
            //solver.addUpperbound(1,1.7) //Add a upper bound to the x[1] variable
            
            
            var x_guess = [1,2] //Guess the initial values of the solution.
            let s = await solver.solve(x_guess) //Solve the equation
            var x = s.x //assign the calculated solution array to the variable x
            document.getElementById("quadratic_demo").value = s.report //Print solver report
            solver.remove() //required to free the memory in C++
            
        }
        ceresSolveQuadratic()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you really mean to expose a live API key?

Comment: Never mind - It looks like the demo API key.